# Should reset button also refresh the pre-loaded results in data table along with its selected parameters

Tags: user-expectation, enterprise

I'm working with large enterprise application, I've many different search parameters on top of the grid to search, and I've Reset and Search buttons below that,when user searches with certain fields, it returns available results under that in data table, Now according to the current behavior, when user clicks "Reset" button all filter parameters get set to its default as it should be but, pre-loaded results vanishes as well.

I think "Reset" button should only reset filter parameters until I click "Search" again with some other filters or may be keeping default filters,
so results will only be refreshed by clicking "Search" button.

I would like to know what would be the better user experience in this scenario.
Please share your thoughts on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The expectations of what gets refreshed / cleared will largely depend on the placement and labeling of the refresh button. You should include a screenshot / wireframe to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

### **Reset to Default**

If you have placed a reset button in your filter/search, **clicking on it should reset all the fields to its initial state.**
- You could reword you 'reset' button to '**reset to default**' if your users are having trouble.
- You could have a '**clear**' button to clear all the filters to null if required.

But keep in mind, there is actually a side effect in keeping reset/clear buttons as this [article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/reset-and-cancel-buttons/) from nngroup says:

> The worst problem about Reset is that users click the button by mistake when they wanted to click Submit. Bang — all your work is gone!

But anyways it depends on how huge your search/filter fields are.

Answer (score 0):

agree with Kishan + it would make sense to clear the results in case the results also change as you type into filters ("instant search") = if the state of filters and state of results are automatically synchronized

if you have to press `Search` to apply any changed filters, then it might make more sense to NOT delete results after pressing `Reset` - however I would suggest to **make the `Search` button disabled initially and enable it only when the filters have changed** (to make it clear whether the current state of results corresponds to the current state of filters on not yet)

there is 1 more option, to start loading all results after clearing filters (if feasible)